# Why my initial variable changes even it is a copy?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to find Palindrome so I copied the list to another variable but when I use `reverse` function, both variables gets reversed. why is this happening?

I can use a loop and append from reverse order one by one, but I really want to know why `reverse` function works this way.

```
arr = list(input())
ar = arr
ar.reverse()
print(arr, ar)
print("YES" if arr == ar else "NO"
```

I expect to find palindrome.

Comment: `ar = arr` does not create a copy. Python variables are just name bindings, references, to objects. So when doing `ar = arr` you are simply telling Python: "Now `ar` should point to the same list as `arr`". So by doing `ar.reverse()`, you reverse the list in memory which is the same one that `arr` points to

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)

Comment: You never copied a list. As an aside, please always use the generic [python] tag for *all python related questions*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `arr.reverse()` reverses the list in place (see also `help(list.reverse)`).

That is, you need to make a copy of the list and then reverse *that*:

```
arr = list(input())
ar = arr.copy()
ar.reverse()
print(arr, ar)
print("YES" if arr == ar else "NO")
```

(Notice how I changed `ar = arr` to `ar = arr.copy()`)

---

You could have "diagnosed" this problem yourself using the `id` function, which returns an unique identifier for each object:

```
>>> arr = list("foo bar beep boop")
>>> id(arr)
4343238976
>>> ar = arr
>>> id(ar)
4343238976
>>> copied = arr.copy()
>>> id(copied)
4341383968
```

Notice how `id(ar)` and `id(arr)` return the same number (4343238976 in this case), meaning they point to the same object. Meanwhile `id(copied)` returns a different number, meaning it's a different object.